# Meaning of "ramp time"?

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal, control, control-system, source

I have read that ramp means slope 
but what is the meaning of "ramp time" ?

For example,if we have a saw-tooth wave,what will be its ramp time?

Please kindly explain with figure/graphics

Comment: The time it takes the signal to go from the minimum slope value to the maximum slope value. (or vice versa on a falling slope)

Comment: @Oldfart In some cases this may be defined as the time between 10% and 90% of the final value, or 5% and 95%, or whatever bounds you want, also. This is more commonly used for what's called "rise time" and "fall time" but I could see "ramp time" being used for those as well.

Comment: @Hearth There are different definitions for ramp/fall times in digital circuits, but the op mentions saw-tooth waveform, where I think my definition is the usual one.